# Subscribing to MailChimp list: Content Type '' not supported

Tags: java, spring, mailchimp, spring-webflux, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to subscribe via Java SpringBoot, but I am facing a problem which I have a hard time to figure out why it's doing this.

```java
public class MailChimpLogic implements ISubscribeLogic {
    private final WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();

    public ResponseEntity subscribe(MailChimpModelRequest request) {
        String baseUri = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/***";
        String username = "***";
        String token = "****-us7";

        MailChimpResponse userSubscribed = builder.build()
                .post()
                .uri(baseUri)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Utils
                        .encodeToString((username + ":" + token).getBytes(UTF_8)))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MailChimpResponse.class)
                .doOnError( e -> {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("something happend" + e);
                })
                .block();


        return new ResponseEntity(userSubscribed, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I tried to add

```java
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.accept( MediaType.ALL ) // I tried to use this one by one
```

And I even tried to use `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8` as content type but no success.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
2019-06-30 14:59:26.070  INFO 28120 --- [           main] ros.config.Application                   : Started Application in 7.696 seconds (JVM running for 8.956)
2019-06-30 14:59:37.567  INFO 28120 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api]    : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-30 14:59:37.567  INFO 28120 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2019-06-30 14:59:37.588  INFO 28120 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type '' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$null$11(BodyInserters.java:329)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$bodyInserterFor$12(BodyInserters.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest.writeTo(DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java:243)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$exchange$0(ExchangeFunctions.java:80)
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.lambda$connect$1(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:74)
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient.lambda$handler$4(HttpClient.java:429)
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:121)
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:84)
    at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380)
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpClientOperations.java:505)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
something happendorg.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type '' not supported
2019-06-30 14:59:45.829 ERROR 28120 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type '' not supported] with root cause

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type '' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$null$11(BodyInserters.java:329) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$bodyInserterFor$12(BodyInserters.java:325) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest.writeTo(DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java:243) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$exchange$0(ExchangeFunctions.java:80) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.lambda$connect$1(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:74) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient.lambda$handler$4(HttpClient.java:429) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:121) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:84) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpClientOperations.java:505) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1183) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
        at ros.logic.MailChimpLogic.subscribe(MailChimpLogic.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
        at ros.controllers.SubscribeController.MailSubscribe(SubscribeController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

MailChimpResponse.class

```
public class MailChimpResponse { // here is the response
    List<MailChimpNewMember> new_members;
    int total_created;
    int total_updated;
    int error_count;
}
```

MailChimpNewMember.class

```
public class MailChimpNewMember {
    String id;
    String email_address;
    String unique_email_id;
    String email_type;
    String status;
    MailChimpMergeFields merge_fields;
    MailChimpStats stats;
    String ip_signup;
    String timestamp_signup;
    String ip_opt;
    Date timestamp_opt;
    int member_rating;
    Date last_changed;
    String language;
    boolean vip;
    String email_client;
    MailChimpLocation location;
    int tags_count;
    String list_id;
}
```

MailChimpStats.class

```
public class MailChimpStats {
    int avg_open_rate;
    int avg_click_rate;
}
```

MailChimpLocation.class

```
public class MailChimpLocation {
    int latitude;
    int longitude;
    int gmtoff;
    int dstoff;
    String country_code;
    String timezone;
}
```

MailChimpModelRequest.class

```
public class MailChimpModelRequest {// here is the request
    private List<MailChimpMember> members;
}
```

MailChimpMergeFields.class

```
public class MailChimpMergeFields {
    private String FNAME;
    private String LNAME;
}
```

MailChimpMember.class

```
public class MailChimpMember {
    private String email_address;
    private String status;
    private MailChimpMergeFields merge_fields;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `MailChimpModelRequest` and `MailChimpResponse`? My guess is that Spring is having trouble serializing `MailChimpModelRequest`.

Comment: I can't post more code, stackoverflow gives me the error that the post contains to much code and i need to give more information about the code.

Comment: Check pastebin for the models: https://pastebin.com/u9TuN385 I removed a couple of properties because they where not needed and mostly empty. Someone told me in an answer that i need to use media type application_json_value but therefor i cant use an object, or can i?

This is the linting error it gave me when i try that: http://prntscr.com/o8m9yg

Comment: Is it possible to use an object as body to mono? will that fix the problem?

Comment: Have you found something usefull for me? @Trein

Comment: I found that one of the problem was in the models, they where private fields so the request was empty.... i created getters setters and constructors for the classes.

But now I have a badrequest error..

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 main problems which I identified with the help of fellow SO memeber @Trein.

The first problem is that my request was empty, this was because the models was missing a getter, setter and constructor.

Next  I used

```
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       .syncBody(request)
```

This was making sure that the application type was set and the body was synced automaticly.

And for the last part I checked my request and it misnamed the json property's. Spring Boot expects Camel Cased Json name's, to change this I used the annotation `@JsonProperty("New-Value")`

And everything was working as a charm!